# Pass data from one view to another view -MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, model

What would be the best method to transfer data from one view to another view? or is this bad practice?

The reason is that i want to display @model.count() from one view to the homepage, basically a summary of all the views on the homepage. There is tempdata, html.helper etc but id like to know the best and most reliable method. Thus avoiding problems further on down the line

here is the code in question

product.cshtml

```
<p>Total amount of Products = @Model.Count()</p>
```

i basically want that same value to display on the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i looked into other methods and resolved the issue by moving the code behind the viewbag into a public method below

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 10)]
    public ActionResult UpdateTotals()
    {
        JobController j = new JobController();
        ViewBag.JobCount = j.JobCount();

        ProductController p = new ProductController();
        ViewBag.ProductCount = p.ProductCount();

        return PartialView("UpdateTotals");
    }
```

then i added the viewbags into a partial view and  using setinterval() javascript,

```
    <div id ="UpdateTotals">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdateTotals");}
</div>
```

```
<script>
    setInterval("$('#UpdateTotals').load('/home/UpdateTotals')", 10000);
</script>
```

i was able to refresh the data constantly to my desire without the mess of pulling data through views via javascript.

hopefully this will help anyone in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to refresh the homepage for the value to actually 'update.' At that point you may as well pass the value back in as a parameter, but I think that's not what you're hoping for.

It probably isn't the cleanest solution, but I would think you'd want your text on the main page to be settable via some javascript/jquery.

Main Page has this snippet:

```
<form id="PassBackVals"
<input type="hidden" name="ProductCount" value="0">
</form> 

<script>$( ".ProductCount" ).change(function() {
  $("$CurrentProductCount").text = $(".ProductCount").val;
});
</script>
```

and the Area displaying the text itself on the main would have something along the lines of

```
<p> I'm currently showing <div id="CurrentProductCount">0</div> Products </p>
```

Then in your product.cshtml, you'd have

```
<script>$(".ProductCount").val = @Model.Count()
$( ".ProductCount" ).change();
</script>
```

Comment: no success im afraid, it presents only 0 on the homepage, when in fact the job count is 24 :/